# Curve imageview corner android

Tags: android, picasso, android-cardview

From last many days I am trying to implement curve corner for my view. I want to design my xml like this image:
 [image]

OR url: [Sample Image](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Of5qL62tBGM48f5uk0AyduZmi3R2dUTY/view?usp=sharing)

All I want is image with curve corner. Width if image will fit its parent while height will be auto.So that full image can be display.

I tried to use `cardView`, `Glide`, `Picasso` and `com.makeramen.roundedimageview.RoundedImageView` library but couldn't get proper result.

adapterHome.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:background="@color/transparent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/card_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_5sdp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/_5sdp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/transparent">
            <ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/progress"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:visibility="gone" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:src="@drawable/influencers"
                android:scaleX="1"
                android:scaleY="1"
                />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/_2sdp"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_1sdp"
                android:background="@color/light_transparent"
                >
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="0.33"
                    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/_5sdp"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    >
                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="@dimen/_12sdp"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/_12sdp"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_happy_smily"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        />
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/total_reaction"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@id/thumbnail"
                        android:text="3k"
                        android:textColor="@color/white"
                        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                        android:gravity="start"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/_10sdp"
                        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/_5sdp"
                        />
                </LinearLayout>
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="0.33"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    >
                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="@dimen/_15sdp"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/_15sdp"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_eye_watch_white"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        />
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/total_watch"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@id/thumbnail"
                        android:text="3k"
                        android:textColor="@color/white"
                        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                        android:gravity="start"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/_10sdp"
                        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/_5sdp"
                        />
                </LinearLayout>
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="0.33"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:gravity="end"
                    >
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/total_time"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@id/thumbnail"
                        android:text="0 Sec"
                        android:textColor="@color/white"
                        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                        android:gravity="end"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/_10sdp"
                        android:paddingRight="@dimen/_5sdp"
                        />
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/post_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/_5sdp"
        android:text="sdsds"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_5sdp"
        android:textSize="@dimen/_12sdp"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

also instead of

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/card_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_5sdp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/_5sdp"
        android:orientation="vertical">
</LinearLayout>
```

I tried to use 
`CardView` but it doesnt worked.

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    xmlns:card_view="https://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@color/grey_300"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
    card_view:cardElevation="0dp"
    card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true">
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Using Picasso:

```
Transformation transformation = new RoundedTransformationBuilder()
   .borderColor(Color.BLACK)
   .cornerRadiusDp(30)
   .oval(false)
   .build();
Picasso.get()
   .load(imageUrl)
   .placeholder(R.drawable.influencers)
   .error(R.drawable.influencers)
   .transform(transformation)
   .into(holder.thumbnail);
```

After using below is my output:
[image: Here, image left blank bottom space]
[Output](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Eo4Emx9OAvNRgWvFR3CCNOSKtWWcmGH9/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Can you show me your Manifest.xml file ?

Comment: Check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2459916/how-to-make-an-imageview-with-rounded-corners/60058794?r=SearchResults&s=5|24.8715#60058794)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use cardview and give card corner radius .
in cardview take any layout then use any view in that layout.

example:

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
        app:cardElevation="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/inercard"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="#ffffff">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="180dp"
                android:id="@+id/imageview"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                />



        </LinearLayout>
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: I followed same logic but it seems that Image is overriding cardview

Comment: use scaletype to fitXY in image view

Comment: and height and width set match parent for image view

Comment: I want to display full image so height of image will be automatic based on width.

Comment: Yes curve is showing but i use image, it override cardview

Comment: what is problem if it override cardview?

Comment: Then curve is hidden behind imageview. So no curve is visible and a square image is displying

Comment: I cannot fix height as it will be auto according to image width

Comment: no problem its not required i just show you implementation from my layout and its work fine.

Comment: sure, but does it solve bottom line issue. Like fit that shaow layout at bottom of image. Also my images are cumming from server.

Comment: in preview it not show, So for testing you have to run this app in emulator or any device.

Comment: please share screenshot of your current situation.

Comment: I also used this layout for server image. So it is no problem for server image.

Comment: Ok, I will share my response here. Can you tell me how are using display images form url into imageview ?

Comment: sure.share your response

Answer (score 1):

You are setting just id to card view instead of doing that do this:

Add this Gradle dependency of card view this:

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    xmlns:card_view="https://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@color/grey_300"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
    card_view:cardElevation="5dp"
    card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true">
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:background="@color/transparent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_5sdp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/_5sdp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/transparent">
        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progress"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/influencers"
            android:scaleX="1"
            android:scaleY="1"
            />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/_2sdp"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_1sdp"
            android:background="@color/light_transparent"
            >
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.33"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/_5sdp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                >
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/_12sdp"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/_12sdp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_happy_smily"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    />
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/total_reaction"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@id/thumbnail"
                    android:text="3k"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                    android:gravity="start"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/_10sdp"
                    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/_5sdp"
                    />
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.33"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:gravity="center"
                >
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/_15sdp"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/_15sdp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_eye_watch_white"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    />
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/total_watch"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@id/thumbnail"
                    android:text="3k"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                    android:gravity="start"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/_10sdp"
                    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/_5sdp"
                    />
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.33"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:gravity="end"
                >
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/total_time"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@id/thumbnail"
                    android:text="0 Sec"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                    android:gravity="end"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/_10sdp"
                    android:paddingRight="@dimen/_5sdp"
                    />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/post_title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/_5sdp"
    android:text="sdsds"
    android:layout_gravity="top"
    android:gravity="top"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_5sdp"
    android:textSize="@dimen/_12sdp"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
    android:scrollHorizontally="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    />
</LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: I followed same logic but it seems that Image is overriding cardview

Comment: Use Card view and Inspect layout by using the inspector and you can find what going on after layout inflation.

Comment: Hoe to inspect in android ?

Comment: Android studio=>Tools => Layout Inspector then select device

Answer (score 0):

use cardview ,scale type centercrop and if corener are not radius then add attribute compactpadding=true, In most of case this attribute forget there for card didn't get corner and image overlap cardview.